# How to convert video on python to .mp4 without ffmpeg?

Tags: python, python-3.x, video-processing

I need to convert videos to .mp4 format I used to ffmpeg but it converts for too long. Is there are a way to convert video to .mp4 in python without ffmpeg?

Comment: try `cv2` also known as `opencv`, i think the specific function you are looking for is called `VideoCapture()`, for more info: [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

UPD `moviepy` depends on `ffmpeg` too (

==

[Zulko/moviepy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy)

```
pip install MoviePy
```

```
import moviepy.editor as moviepy
clip = moviepy.VideoFileClip("myvideo.avi")
clip.write_videofile("myvideo.mp4")
```

As per `MoviePy` documentation, there is no `ffmpeg` dependencies:

> MoviePy depends on the Python modules [Numpy](http://www.scipy.org/install.html), [imageio](http://imageio.github.io/), [Decorator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator), and [tqdm](https://github.com/noamraph/tqdm), which will be automatically installed during MoviePy's installation.

> [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is not strictly required, but needed if you want to incorporate texts. It can also be used as a backend for GIFs, though you can also create GIFs with MoviePy without ImageMagick.

> [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml) is needed for video and sound previews (not relevant if you intend to work with MoviePy on a server but essential for advanced video editing by hand).

> For advanced image processing, you will need one or several of the following packages:

> - The Python Imaging Library (PIL) or, even better, its branch [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

- [Scipy](http://www.scipy.org/) (for tracking, segmenting, etc.) can be used to resize video clips if PIL and OpenCV are not installed.
- [Scikit Image](http://scikit-image.org/download.html) may be needed for some advanced image manipulation.
- [OpenCV 2.4.6](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/) or a more recent version (one that provides the package `cv2`) may be needed for some advanced image manipulation.
- [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/)

Comment: FFMPEG will be automatically downloaded/installed by imageio

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick program that will convert all video files of a particular type in a directory to another type and put them in another directory.
I had to install `moviepy` using `Homebrew` for it to work rather than rely on `PyCharm`'s package installation.

```
import moviepy.editor as moviepy
import os

FROM_EXT    = "mkv"
TO_EXT      = "mp4"
SOURCE_DIR  = "/Volumes/Seagate Media/Movies/MKVs"
DEST_DIR    = "/Volumes/Seagate Media/Movies/MP4s"

for file in os.listdir(SOURCE_DIR):
    if file.lower().endswith(FROM_EXT.lower()):
        from_path   = os.path.join(SOURCE_DIR, file)
        to_path     = os.path.join(DEST_DIR, file.rsplit('.', 1)[0]) + '.' + TO_EXT

        print(f"Converting {from_path} to {to_path}")

        clip = moviepy.VideoFileClip(from_path)
        clip.write_videofile(to_path)
```